# How do I refresh the foreignkey_set after a destructive operation in Django?

Tags: django

I realized that the object_set on a model doesn't update if I delete items through `filter().delete()` (which is okay) however I'd like to update the `_set` after deletion so that this passes:

```
def test_prefetch(self):
    game = Game.objects.prefetch_related('bubble_set').get()
    game.fill_board()
    self.assertEqual(game.bubble_set.count(), game.width * game.height)
    game.bubble_set.filter(x=5).delete()
    # Fails
    self.assertNotEqual(game.bubble_set.count(), game.width * game.height)
    game = Game.objects.prefetch_related('bubble_set').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refetch the object. So can do `game = Game.objects.prefetch_related('bubble_set').get()` just after `.delete()`.